# Best behaviour to update ImageView in ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, bitmap

We have ListView with Images. Images downloads from our server. Then saves to Storage and puts to cache like this:

```
private static final Hashtable<String, Bitmap> cachePhoto = new Hashtable<String, Bitmap>();
```

So in getView after 1st added we gets Images from cache and sets it to ImageView:

```
i.setImageBitmap(photo);
```

And now we have some lags while scrolling on many devices. But wanted to smooth scrolling. How can i avoid lags?

Comment: There is not enough info in your question to find out what is causing the performance lag. Maybe you should post your `getView()` and the place where you update the cache etc. **Recommendation**: You should use volly (and its `NetworkImageView`), no point re-inventing the wheel: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17571759/827110

Comment: In getView i invoke my ViewHolder and trying to set Image.

1) Tries to take image from sd-card (and cache). 
2) if no img, then downloads from web in AsyncTask.

So lags in getView is when creating AsyncTask...

Comment: How do you know it lags when creating `AsyncTask`? You think or you have carried out test to figure out that this is the bottleneck? In either case, I think its very hard to fix your problem unless you post code. As there is no general solution.. you must be doing something which causes the lag..

Answer (score 0):

we need more of your code or I can just recommend you to check this library
https://github.com/thest1/LazyList

Comment: LazyList uses LinkedHashMap. It's make scrolling more smoothly, but still have lags at 2.3 devices =/