# Android Studio Cannot resolve symbol StringRequest, POST, or Response

Tags: android-studio, undefined-symbol

I am writing a java class on android studio to connect with a mysql database, but i keep receiving "cannot resolve symbol" error. No idea why. Any Help.
Here is a part of the program:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.net.ResponseCache;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class RegisterRequest extends StringRequest {
    private static final String REGISTER_REQUEST_URL = "****/Register.php";
    private Map<String, String> params;
    public RegisterRequest(String username, String password, String email, Response.Listener<String> listner){
        super(Method.POST, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL, listner, null);
        params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("username",username);
        params.put("password",password);
        params.put("email",email);
}
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams() {
        return params;
 }
 }
```

I receiving error "Cannot resolve symbol" for: StringRequest, Response, POST
Also error "Method does not override Method from it superclass" for: @Override

Note: all volley imports are marked as unused.

Any Help ?!!

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?  The idea of downloading and compiling the source into a local library doesn't feel right--doesn't seem like this should be a problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this issue:

- download the volley library and create a **libs** folder in your **app** directory
- then copy and paste the volley library into the libs folder you created.
- Finally, right click on the volley library and select add as a library and clean your project.

If an error remains, press ALT + Enter at each error. It may occur where `super(Method.POST, ..` can give you an error change it to :

```
super(Request.Method.POST
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you use ***'compile com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'*** as your volley library? If yes, don't use it. It's not yet maintained (the updates) - deprecated. I suggest you use the original library (copy and paste this one below)

***compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'*** .

For more discussion just to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17571759/how-do-you-use-the-android-volley-api) .