# Android - Hassle free way to use devices Network without Threads and AsyncTask etc?

Tags: java, android, api, exception, networking

What is the quickest, cleanest and easiest way to perform **Network activities** **in Java / Android** without having to deal with the mess of AsyncTask, Threads and other gulp? Is there possibly a **library** that handles most of the work for the programmer?

My goal at the moment is to ask an API-End-Point to give me a JSON String back which I can put into a map to do all kinds of things.

**This is the code so far:**

```
   Map<String, String> launch;
   private static String url = "https://api.spacexdata.com/v2/launches/latest";
   private JSONObject jsonObject;

   OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();
        Response response = null;
        response = okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute();
        String informationString = response.body().string().toString();

     /* Just grabing the information so really uninteresting */
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(informationString);
        launch.put("missionName", jsonObject.get("mission_name").toString());
        launch.put("rocketName", jsonObject.getJSONObject("rocket").get("rocket_name").toString());
        launch.put("block", jsonObject.getJSONObject("rocket").getJSONObject("firstfirst_stage").getJSONArray("cores").getString(3));
        launch.put("flightNumber", jsonObject.get("flight_number").toString());
```

---

**The error I'm getting is NetworkOnMainThreadActivity**. I've tried a ton of things to avoid / solve it but all end up with just more exceptions which are irrelevant at the moment.

```
    W/System.err: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
W/System.err:     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1448)
W/System.err:     at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:102)
W/System.err:     at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:90)
W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:787)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:40)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:185)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:149)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:84)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:213)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:134)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:113)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:125)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)
W/System.err:     at com.pushfurther.spacelaunchtracker.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)
W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7174)
W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1220)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2908)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3030)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

two of the most popular ones are Volley and Retrofit,I use Volley its simple and gets the job done for me,Retrofit is just as good. Have a look at how to use volley here; [How do you use the Android Volley API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17571759/how-do-you-use-the-android-volley-api), or you can look at tutorials online,you'll find these libraries less hectic than asyncTask.

Comment: This solved my problem, use volley! It is easy to use and understandable thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad i helped,Happy Coding