# Post Method using Volley not working

Tags: android, json, android-volley, dhc

Hi i am using `Volley` for my login page. I need to pass data like this manner

```
{
userID : '-988682425884628921',
email :'aditya@vyas.com',
passwd : '123ss'
}
```

I am using POST Method to send data,I already check in DHC, The Api is working fine in DHC and I am getting [JSON Response](http://pastie.org/10854767), But when i try with Volley i am not able to get response. and not even any error in my logcat.

JAVA code

```
 RequestQueue mVolleyQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    CustomRequest req = new CustomRequest(Request.Method.POST,url,null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.v("tag","login response " + response);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.v("tag","login error response " + error.getMessage());
        }
    }){
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();

            params.put("userID", "-988682425884628921");
            params.put("email", "aditya@vyas.com");
            params.put("passwd", "123ss");
            return params;
        }


            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                return headers;
        }
    };
    mVolleyQueue.add(req);
```

Error

```
05-28 09:20:14.696 2450-2468/com.android.msahakyan.expandablenavigationdrawer E/tag﹕ parseNetworkError is ! null
05-28 09:20:14.697 2450-2468/com.android.msahakyan.expandablenavigationdrawer E/tag﹕ parseNetworkError status code : 400
05-28 09:20:14.697 2450-2468/com.android.msahakyan.expandablenavigationdrawer E/tag﹕ parseNetworkError message : <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid Header</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request has an invalid header name.</p>
</BODY></HTML>


    }
```

Comment: Try using StringRequest instead of JsonObjectRequest. I see that the JSON is in JSONArray format, so that might be the problem.

Comment: @SomnathPal stringrequest also not working

Comment: You are passing parameters in body, need to override getParams() method and pass parameters there

Comment: @Dory i tried with Arth Tilva's answer too

Comment: What is JsonStringRequest

Comment: Have tried for JsonArrayRequest ? coz i m seeing your response in JSONArray..!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved your problem. Just used `JsonArrayRequest` and passed parameters in `JsonObject` form:

```
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("userID", "userid");
    params.put("email","email");
    params.put("passwd", "password");
    JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, "url", new JSONObject(params),
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    System.out.println("response -->> " + response.toString());
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    System.out.println("change Pass response -->> " + error.toString());
                }
            });

    request.setRetryPolicy(new

            DefaultRetryPolicy(60000,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));


    Volley.newRequestQueue(activity).add(request);
```

**No need of overriding `getParams()` or `getHeaders()`.**

**Problem : 1** 
You were getting **response code 500** because the server was accepting the `params` as `JsonObject` and we are trying to feed `String`.

**Problem : 2**
You were using `JsonObjectRequet` but the response from the server was in `JsonArray` so you need to use `JsonArrayRequest` to accept the response in `JsonArray`

Try and let me know this helps or not :)

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem. I had overwritten the Content-Type in the getHeaders Method:

`headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");`

but Volley itself added a Content-Type parameter, so there were two of those parameters. Delete the line had solved my Problem.

Comment: You made my day, have been struggling since hours, and this was the reason :)

Comment: you rock dude, I am from 2020 here ahahahahah

Answer (score 1):

You need to override  `protected Map<String, String> getParams()` to pass parameters in POST.

```html
 JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            url, params,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d("Login Response", response.toString());


                   hidepDialog();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            System.out.println(error.getStackTrace());
            VolleyLog.d("ErrorVolley", "Error: " + error.getStackTrace());
            hidepDialog();
        }
    }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("userID", "2"));
                params.put("email","aa@a.kl");
                params.put("passwd", "ddddd");

                return params;
            }
        };
```

Comment: still same no change ::(

Comment: if change it with stringrequest it shows BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for

Comment: I checked about Error 500 and found that this error may be caused from the server side. Its not any fault of your code  @AdityaVyas

Comment: Don't have experience with DHC, but if its working in Postman (using POST) then you should get atleast response from your web service.

Comment: 500 is the server side exception, contact web dev. and ask why it is throwing exception.

Comment: might be you are not sending all parameters you need to, then also it may thtrow exception

Comment: @ArthTilva i am sending same parameter which i have in DHC and there i am able to get response :(

Comment: If you can provide the API link and params, I can check.

Comment: It may happen your server is only accepting JSON and you might be sending string.

Comment: @jankigadhiya then what is the solution for that

Answer (score 0):

Beware of content-type header. Volley handles it differently from other headers and it's not shown in Map<> Headers. Instead of overriding getHeaders() method to set content-type, you should override getBodyContentType() like this:

```
@Override
public String getBodyContentType()
{
    return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i have same problem use this :

```
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }) {

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getParams()  {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8");
            headers.put("UN", UserName);
            headers.put("PW", PassWord);
            return headers;


        }

    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
     requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

Just need to add `headers.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8");` to parms

good luck.