# Fetching data using volley for specified search from android application

Tags: php, android, android-volley

I have a doubt actually regarding volley in android. I know how to fetch data from sql server database through php code which does not take any data from the android app like

```
  select * from table;
```

and if I'd like to fetch data from database with php code containing statements like

```
select * from tablename where field1='something';
```

I need to send data from android app to php. Can we actually do it using Volley. If so please tell me how to send data to php file from android.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP library that you are using is not relevant in this problem. You need to allow for data input in PHP script. Either by POST or GET variables. (look at this tutorial http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_get_post.htm)

In terms of creating request with proper parameters take a look at this question: [Volley - POST/GET parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626032/volley-post-get-parameters)

Comment: Actually i have gone through what u have posted methods there are two methods called createMyReqSuccessListener(), createMyReqErrorListener(). Can u tell me what are those.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can.

Follow the official Volley guide, [here](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)