# getParams not calling in StringRequest Android

Tags: android, android-volley

I am using `StringRequest` to send the `Files` to server. I am using the following code:

```
final MultipartEntityBuilder mHttpEntity = buildMultipartEntity(files_to_upload, params);

        Response.Listener<String> rListner = new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                if(response != null) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Constants.ACTION_RESPONSE_RECEIVED);
                    intent.putExtra(Constants.RESPONSE, response);
                    intent.putExtra(SignupActivity.EXTRA_ACTION_RESPONSE, SignupActivity.EXTRA_SIGNUP_DATA);
                    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(MyApplication.getContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);
                }
            }
        };

        Response.ErrorListener errorListner = new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Constants.ACTION_RESPONSE_RECEIVED);
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(MyApplication.getContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);
                if(error != null && error.getMessage() != null) {
//                    Toast.makeText(MyApplication.getContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else {
                    Log.i(TAG, "postRequestToServer: onErrorResponse : error message null");
                }
            }
        };

        StringRequest jsonObjectRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, rListner, errorListner)
        {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                return params;
            }

//            @Override
//            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
//                return params;
//            }

            @Override
            public String getBodyContentType() {
                return mHttpEntity.build().getContentType().getValue();
            }
//
            @Override
            public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
                ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                try {
                    mHttpEntity.build().writeTo(bos);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    VolleyLog.e("IOException writing to ByteArrayOutputStream");
                }
                return bos.toByteArray();
            }
        };

private MultipartEntityBuilder buildMultipartEntity(String files_to_upload, HashMap<String, String> params) {

        MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();

        String[] arr_files = files_to_upload.split("##");
        for(int i = 0; i < arr_files.length; i++) {
            String filePath = arr_files[i];
            if(filePath == null || filePath.length() == 0)
                continue;
            File file = new File(filePath);
            String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(arr_files[i]);
            String mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);

            builder.addBinaryBody("userfile", file, ContentType.create(mimeType), file.getName());
//            builder.addPart("userfile", new FileBody(file));
        }

        try {
            for (String key: params.keySet())
                builder.addPart(key, new StringBody(params.get(key)));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            VolleyLog.e("UnsupportedEncodingException");
        }

        return builder;
    }
```

But the issue is `getParams` is not being called. Server is expecting paramters, I tried to send using `EntityBuilder` but still I am having errors in sending the parameters.

Can anyone please let me know how can I upload files using
 `StringRequest with Parameters`?

Comment: As far as I understood your question:: When you use Volley to make a `StringRequest`, you are making an HTTP GET, expecting tex/plain as response... When you change to a POST, [you can check this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16795805/4903925) for related content...

Comment: No, I using post to send the data. `getParams` is not being called when I override `getBody()` How to make request with `Parameters`

Answer (score 0):

Your getParams() is not getting called because StringRequest.java inherits from Request.java. Now in Request.java, if you look at the getBody() method,

```
public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String, String> params = getParams();
        if (params != null && params.size() > 0) {
            return encodeParameters(params, getParamsEncoding());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

you can see getParams() is getting called from getBody() method. Now while making your request `StringRequest jsonObjectRequest`, you are overriding the getBody() method which means your getParams() will not get called. This is the reason why getParams() is not getting called.

**EDIT**
Create this custom volley request class that takes params inside the request constructor

```
public class CustomRequest extends Request<String> {

    private Listener<String> listener;
    private Map<String, String> params;

    public CustomRequest(int method, String url, Map<String, String> params,
            Listener<String> reponseListener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(method, url, errorListener);
        this.listener = reponseListener;
        this.params = params;
    }

    protected Map<String, String> getParams()
            throws com.android.volley.AuthFailureError {
        return params;
    };

    @Override
    protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        try {
            String jsonString = new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
            return Response.success(jsonString, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        } catch (JSONException je) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(je));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(String response) {
        listener.onResponse(response);
    }
}
```

Now send your request through this class. instead of overriding getParams(), just create a hashmap for your params, and pass them inside the constructor.

Comment: Then how to send the parameters?

Comment: With this, you can not send file. I was overriding `getBody` to send the file.

Comment: this class extends from Request class. You can anytime override `getBody()` method

Comment: the problem will again be the same that when I will override `getBody`, `getParams` will not be called.

Comment: Ohh sorry I din't realise. You can check this link http://stackoverflow.com/q/32240177/1320616 . It might help you

Answer (score 0):

Use `getparams` and `getHeader` metods:

```
@Override
protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
    Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
    parameters.put("product_id", "4");
    parameters.put("count", Productcount.getText().toString());
    parameters.put("type", cashstatus);
    parameters.put("description", "Matn bo'ladi");
    parameters.put("phone_number", "946287009");
    parameters.put("on_map", address);
    return parameters;
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
    headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
    return headers;
}
```