# How to add referal to a volley request

Tags: android, android-volley, traffic

I am building an android app for my website, I am using Volley to make network request. I want to know the amount of traffic that's coming from the app. And I want differentiate the traffic source from others (Chrome, Firefox etc). So how do I add a referrer to a volley GET request?

Comment: use google analytics instead

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626032/volley-post-get-parameters