# how to use Java Api to post and retrieve data from database?

Tags: android, json

I need to hit serverside Database and retrieve or post data from server side DataBase.

what i have is .json files and path for the api

How to do this???

Do I need to use any third party libraries ??

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use third party libraries, you can just use [HttpUrlConnection](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) class which is a pure Java Library. On the other hand there are some third party which are very easy and clear to send and receive requests such as [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html) and [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) etc. 
 It is your decision to use whatever you like. I would recommend you to use Volley, because it is a framework of Google.

Comment: but how to attach json file if i used HttpUrlConnection

Comment: bacause i need to read .json file in my assets folder and need to send request body in that json along with url

Comment: Read json file and append the readed string as parameter to post request. If it is not working checkout uploading file example. http://androidexample.com/Upload_File_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=83

Comment: This is the example of how to add parameters to post request. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626032/volley-post-get-parameters

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://square.github.io/okhttp/ to send or receive data from the server. Tutorial available in http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaLibrary-OkHttp/article.html, Hope this may help you..