# Kotlin vs Java @Overrides

Tags: java, android, kotlin

As shown here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/16639438/8949356, in Java you can override the function of a declared class when it is public

But I want to know how to do this exact same code in Kotlin, I've tried a lot but haven't found anywhere something on this topic. And I could just go and do this in Java but the rest of my code is in Kotlin, plus I just can't stay with this kind of doubt; Kotlin feels like a great tool to me and want to learn it all.

Comment: Tell us what you tried in the code and didn't working

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to override method, Use `override` keyword.

Like this.

```
override fun addNumber(i : Int) {
  val sum = i+10
}
```

You must declare method that be overrided with `open` keyword.
If you don't, You can't override it.

```
open fun addNumber(i : T)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can override functions and properties with the [`override` keyword](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#overriding-methods). Note though, that in Kotlin, classes are not extensible by default, so you have to declare the parent with `open` (i.e. `open class MyClass()`) if you want to extend it (Java classes are still extensible unless `final`).