# Android example code to update MySQL data using Volley?

Tags: android, mysql, android-volley

Is there any way to update MySQL data using volley just by passing the value in URL without using data_model class ?

Suggest me a Simple and efficient solution...

Answer (score 0):

If you want simply then you can use this below method,

```
String updateApi = yourserverpath +"?type=fruit&name=apple"
```

**type** is your **key1** then **fruit** is your **value1**

**name** is your **key2** then **apple** is your **value2**

And call this api direct into **volley request** method it will work sure.
But one think actually its not good practice you need to use volley with parameters refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626032/volley-post-get-parameters), its is a good way to achieve this.