# put parameter in request volley android with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-volley

I need make request with Volley and kotlin my cod is

```
val stringReq = StringRequest(
Request.Method.GET, url,
Response.Listener<String> { response ->

var strResp = response.toString()
            val jsonObj: JSONObject = JSONObject(strResp)
            val jsonArray: JSONArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("curso")

for (i in 0 until jsonArray.length()) {

                var jsonInner: JSONObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
                listGeral.add(jsonInner.get("interpret").toString());
                listGeral2.add(jsonInner.get("titel").toString());
                listGeral3.add(jsonInner.get("id").toString());

            }

},
        Response.ErrorListener {

        })
    queue.add(stringReq)
```

Now I need send 3 parameters for php. How do I put instruction for send parameter?

Comment: This has already been asked and answered: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16639438/112263

Comment: This response are in JAVA I need in Kotlin

Answer (score 3):

you can write the below code after `Response.ErrorListener`

```
      val sr: StringRequest = object : StringRequest(Method.POST, "url",
                Response.Listener { response -> 

                     //your response
              },
                Response.ErrorListener { error -> 
                     //your error
              }) {
            override fun getParams(): Map<String, String> {
                val params: MutableMap<String, String> = HashMap()
                params["user"] = "YOUR USERNAME"
                params["pass"] = "YOUR PASSWORD"
                return params
            }

            @Throws(AuthFailureError::class)
            override fun getHeaders(): Map<String, String> {
                val params: MutableMap<String, String> = HashMap()
                params["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                return params
            }
        }
        queue.add(sr)
```

Comment: Javad Dehban look for this image of error

http://www.kmshow.com.br/kotlin/error.png

Comment: Now I test your script is Done but when I put my "for" into (response) the aplication crash

Comment: When I put a loop fo get itens the json the app crash when run

Comment: This works for me by changing my `content-type` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`